# Posting to PHP from multiple forms

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have multiple buttons declared like this:

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="sendSMSTelstra.php" method = "post">      
<input type="image" name="imageField1" id="imageField1" 
     onmouseup="SendCMD(1)" src="img/ButtonBlue.png" width="42" height="42">
<img src="img/on.png" alt="" width="40" height="40" id="IO1img" name="IO1img"/>  
 </form>
```

So that's multiple forms...
When a button is pressed, the JavaScript function SendCMD is called which sets the value:

```
document.getElementById('imageField X').value = "testing";
```

where X refers to which button was pressed

I have a problem though now, as within my PHP file, I don't know which button id to reference

```
$_POST['imageField X']
```

I have tried creating a hidden type, in it's own form - with the idea of it being a 'global' variable...

```
<form name="hiddenform" id="hiddenform" action="sendSMSTelstra.php" method = "post">
    <input type="hidden" name="sendSMS" id="sendSMS" value = "1">               
</form>
```

Which is updated in the SendCMD function:

```
document.getElementById('sendSMS').value = "testing";
```

But this isn't working, because the post only happens in the button forms....
Any help would be great

Comment: with $_POST, the value of the form/form field is submitted. Where is your value attribute in your input?

Comment: Where is `imageField X` field ?

Comment: imageField X, refers to which every button was pressed. first button has ID="imageField1", and so on.

Comment: if I set the value within each image form, I have the same trouble in knowing which button was pressed within my PHP file.. which is why I'm trying to update the 'global' hidden form value, so that I know what ID to access from PHP

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a wired way how you manage and create your forms.

But ok, you should define a hidden value in every form button you created.

`<input type="hidden" name="formid" id="formid" value="x">`

then its more comfortable for you to detect wich form is used.

The name and id is the same in every form, you only need to change the value of `x`, on your PHP side you have then the variable in `$_POST['formid']`.

Comment: hey, I have tried this thanks, but it doesn't seem to work... it doesn't set the value for all hidden inputs, just the first one

Comment: it seams you have an error in your syntax some where, can you post the relevant file on any paste service? e.g pastbin or debian paste

Comment: is this what you mean by pastebin? http://pastebin.com/HpqSQ37a
That's my HTML for one button - they are all the same except for ID's (not the input hidden IDs - they are the same) - in my SendCMD(x) function, all I am doing is 

        document.getElementById("sendSMS").value = "test";

the sendSMSTelstra.php page that loads prints value posted, which isn't "test", but the value "1". It seems as though the function is implemented first, and then the value is set before POST happens...